# How to open google maps from an IONIC app

Tags: ionic-framework, google-maps-api-3, ionic4

I have an IONIC app that gets a certain location as lat, long from a service call. I want to give a functionality in my app where the user can click on a button and google maps should open with the location already marked.

I have tried
`https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/launch-navigator`
but its somehow when the google maps opens I cant find a way there message.

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

This is probably because the location does not exactly point to somewhere on a road (i guess), but even if it's not how can I get navigation to the nearest road

Comment: Why is launch-navigator not working for you? Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0):

This Plugin Only works on actual devices and not on a browser